# if statements with and or - not working

Tags: python, if-statement

I have this code, but for the line "if c=a and d=b+1:", it says SyntaxError: invalid syntax. What is wrong with it?

```
if c=a and d=b+1:
    print("YES")
```

Comment: You should use `==` not `=`

Comment: What's the objective of this piece of code?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `==` for comparison. `=` is for assignment to a variable

```
if c==a and d==b+1:
```